# How to fix the plot Range in list log linear plot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have 8 plots, and all these plots are generated using ListLogLinearPlot function. and later I have used Show command put all plot in one single figure, but could not able to fix the plot range.

```
Y = 2*^11;
ρ = 7850;
aa = 0.1*0.1;
Iyy = 0.1^4/12;
L=4;
ansys = {{34.108, 112.53, 226.24, 299.01, 432.03, 642.34, 876.13, 
    000.00, 1226.0, 1549.0, 1880.1, 2030.4, 2342.3, 2756.7, 3159.1, 
    3311.9, 3710.5, 4198.8, 4640.3, 4788.8}, {34.085, 112.42, 226.24, 
    296.24, 428.60, 638.60, 876.12, 960.90, 1196.6, 1516.5, 1795.2, 
    1881.1, 2232.8, 2562.2, 2835.3, 3162.2, 3498.5, 3832.8, 4239.4, 
    4652.9}, {33.991, 111.96, 226.24, 280.75, 405.66, 552.40, 669.71, 
    876.14, 1030.8, 1229.6, 1524.3, 1703.9, 1880.5, 2124.4, 2369.1, 
    2727.9, 2927.8, 3162.1, 3439.9, 3726.4}, {33.873, 111.26, 226.24, 
    235.94, 340.38, 449.22, 641.80, 838.74, 876.17, 1055.1, 1232.3, 
    1473.8, 1593.9, 1880.2, 1969.5, 2189.0, 2389.2, 2688.2, 2826.2, 
    3159.1}, {33.355, 94.087, 118.68, 226.24, 270.06, 332.20, 429.88, 
    520.47, 640.79, 720.67, 876.11, 898.40, 1023.7, 1135.7, 1240.3, 
    1362.3, 1521.7, 1590.1, 1753.4, 1880.2}, {32.647, 62.162, 113.15, 
    181.10, 226.24, 280.62, 328.47, 412.98, 458.67, 559.45, 640.01, 
    690.67, 803.53, 876.13, 916.05, 1007.3, 1082.3, 1175.0, 1246.7, 
    1332.4}};
ansys = 2*π*ansys;
ansysbeta = Surd[(ρ*aa*ansys^2*L^4)/(Y*Iyy), 4];
ansysbeta1 = ansysbeta[[All, 1]];
ansysbeta2 = ansysbeta[[All, 2]];
ansysbeta3 = ansysbeta[[All, 3]];
ansysbeta4 = ansysbeta[[All, 4]];

xaxis = {0.001, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 3, 5};

data5 = Transpose[{xaxis, ansysbeta1}];
data6 = Transpose[{xaxis, ansysbeta2}];
data7 = Transpose[{xaxis, ansysbeta3}];
data8 = Transpose[{xaxis, ansysbeta4}];
p[5] = ListLogLinearPlot[data5, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.006]}];
p[6] = ListLogLinearPlot[data6, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.006]}];
p[7] = ListLogLinearPlot[data7, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.006]}];
p[8] = ListLogLinearPlot[data8, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.006]}];
Show[Table[p[i], {i, 5, 8}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: my final plot]

Comment: Please share the code you are using

Comment: tried `Show[plot1, plot2, ..., plot8, PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: Yes I did still i am getting the same result

Comment: It looks to me as if you are seeing the full range of the data

Comment: `Show[ Array[ p, 4, 5],  PlotRange -> { {-7.5, 2.3},  {0, 20} }, 
 Frame -> True ]`

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

The plot you wish to make can be accomplished with `ListLogLinearPlot` alone. Like so:

```
Y = 2*^11;
ρ = 7850;
aa = 0.1*0.1;
Iyy = 0.1^4/12;
L = 4;
ansys = 2*π*
   {{34.108, 112.53, 226.24, 299.01, 432.03, 642.34, 876.13, 
    000.00, 1226.0, 1549.0, 1880.1, 2030.4, 2342.3, 2756.7, 3159.1, 
    3311.9, 3710.5, 4198.8, 4640.3, 4788.8}, {34.085, 112.42, 226.24, 
    296.24, 428.60, 638.60, 876.12, 960.90, 1196.6, 1516.5, 1795.2, 
    1881.1, 2232.8, 2562.2, 2835.3, 3162.2, 3498.5, 3832.8, 4239.4, 
    4652.9}, {33.991, 111.96, 226.24, 280.75, 405.66, 552.40, 669.71, 
    876.14, 1030.8, 1229.6, 1524.3, 1703.9, 1880.5, 2124.4, 2369.1, 
    2727.9, 2927.8, 3162.1, 3439.9, 3726.4}, {33.873, 111.26, 226.24, 
    235.94, 340.38, 449.22, 641.80, 838.74, 876.17, 1055.1, 1232.3, 
    1473.8, 1593.9, 1880.2, 1969.5, 2189.0, 2389.2, 2688.2, 2826.2, 
    3159.1}, {33.355, 94.087, 118.68, 226.24, 270.06, 332.20, 429.88, 
    520.47, 640.79, 720.67, 876.11, 898.40, 1023.7, 1135.7, 1240.3, 
    1362.3, 1521.7, 1590.1, 1753.4, 1880.2}, {32.647, 62.162, 113.15, 
    181.10, 226.24, 280.62, 328.47, 412.98, 458.67, 559.45, 640.01, 
    690.67, 803.53, 876.13, 916.05, 1007.3, 1082.3, 1175.0, 1246.7, 
    1332.4}};
xaxis = {0.001, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 3, 5};
ansysbeta = Surd[(ρ*aa*ansys^2*L^4)/(Y*Iyy), 4];
data = Transpose[{xaxis, #}] & /@ Transpose[ansysbeta[[All, ;; 4]]];
ListLogLinearPlot[data,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotRangePadding -> {{.5, 1}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Brown, Magenta},
  Mesh -> All,
  MeshStyle -> Black]
```

[image: plot]